# Is PHP htmlentities (with UTF-8 encoding specified) enough for protecting XSS

Tags: php, xss, security

Assume the template code in PHP is

```
<div>
  <? echo htmlentities($unfiltered_text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
</div>
```

Is the following code safe to against `ALL possible XSS`?

is not, can you give an example? Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget the PHP closing statement before your </div>

Comment: What following code are you referring to? Or do you mean the preceding code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, htmlentities will convert all characters which have a special meaning in HTML.